# How to find out which system component disabled the hibernation? (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

Installing a VMware Workstation 7.1 Windows 7 VM, and find that I cannot enable hibernation with `powercfg -h on`. Windows says

```
An internal system component has disabled hibernation
```

What's wrong and how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it. Windows 7 and 8 does not allow hibernation if it is installed inside a VHD.

Windows 7 powercfg.exe does not make it explicit. Windows 8 does, a screen shot below:

[image]

I cannot figure out the reason why Microsoft impose such limitation. If he puts hiberfil.sys onto a partition from a *real disk* , things should be able to go smooth.

**BUT, is there a way to know it on Windows 7, through a system log or something?**

Answer (score 3):

Use the registry to enable hibernation back.

1. start regedit.exe
2. go to the key **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentCongtrolSet\Control\Power**
3. change the value **HibernateEnabled** from **0** to **1**.

Now reboot and look if you have hibernation back.

Comment: Checked that key, no luck, **HibernateEnabled** is already set to 1.

Comment: ok, in this case set it 0 and reboot and now try to run the powercfg command.

Comment: Changing from 1 to 0 caused only that it disappeared from System menu, I still cannot enable it.